# Android Emulator Won't Start in Eclipse "requested operation requires elevation

Tags: android

has anyone experienced this?  I had it working and then broke it somehow.  Haven't been able to reinstall and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically that you need to run it with administrator privileges.

Check these links for a solution:

http://www.techrena.net/windows/fix-requested-operation-requires-elevation-error/

http://gaskell.org/the-requested-operation-requires-elevation-in-windows-vista/

http://appvgeek.blogspot.com/2010/08/requested-operation-requires-elevation.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=254561